# Distinguish the parameter passed as a query string in hot towel template that uses durandal

Tags: routes, durandal, hottowel

I have a hot towel application that uses durandal for routing. One of the routes that is defined in config file looks as follows:

```
   {
     url: 'charts/:id',
     moduleId: 'viewmodels/charts',
     name: 'Charts',
     visible: false
   }
```

Charts is a viewmodel that displays data for patient id or agency id. From patient viewmodel I am sending patient id and from agency viewmodel I am sending agency id.

My question is how can I know in activate method of Charts viewmodel whether the parameter in url is patient id or agency id ?

```
vm.activate = function (routeData) {
   ////routeData will have routeData.id. How can I know if this is patient id or agency id ?
};
```

Comment: how bout adding an additional var to distinguish it? Like url: 'charts/:type/:id'

Comment: @zewa666 This works. You can add this as a answer and I will mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve the described scenario, the easiest thing is to add a second parameter which will distinguish your calling type.

Here is a sample route:

```
{
 url: 'charts/:type/:id',
 moduleId: 'viewmodels/charts',
 name: 'Charts',
 visible: false
}
```

In your activate you should now have two parameters to check against

```
vm.activate = function (routeData) {
  ////routeData.type, routeData.id
  if(routeData.type === "agency") {
  }
};
```